# Can nVidia Quadro P600 support 1900x1200 resolution?

Tags: resolution

Can nVidia Quadro P600 support 1900x1200 resolution?
All I see is Maximum in the specs sheets I've found.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Remember that If you need to [edit] your post you can... Give it a look to [help] in general (and to [ask] and [why-vote](https://superuser.com/help/why-vote)). Enjoy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems yes (specifications from [this page](https://www.pny.com/nvidia-quadro-p600))

> Number of Displays Supported   4
>   Maximum DP 1.4 Resolution   HDR 5120 x 2880 at 60Hz (30-bit color)
>   5K Display Support  HDR 5120 x 2880 at 60Hz (30-bit color)
>   4K Display Support  HDR 4096 x 2160 at 60Hz or 3840 x 2160 at 60Hz
>   Maximum DVI-D DL Resolution     2560 x 1600 at 60Hz via 3rd party adapter
>   **Maximum DVI-D SL Resolution   1920 x 1200 at 60Hz via optional adapter**
>   Quadro and NVS Display Resolution Support

Answer (score 0):

From [official datasheet](https://www.nvidia.com/content/dam/en-zz/Solutions/design-visualization/quadro-product-literature/301995-DS-NV-Quadro-Pascal-P600-US-03Feb17-NV-fnl-WEB.pdf), it supports up to 5k resolution. As far as I know the display mode (eg 1920x1200) depends on your monitor. The card can output any resolutions lower than its maximum supported. You can even create your own custom resolution for the card to output.